# Detect whether a type is an zero-element array?

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, c++11, type-traits

Consider the following function :

```
template <typename Type>
void f(const Type& x)
```

I would like to do something special (without specialization) in it whether the passed type is an empty `std::tuple` or an empty `std::array`. For a tuple of nu elements, I can use `std::is_same<Type, std::tuple<>>::value` but what trick can I use to detect an zero-element array ?

(I am searching for a solution that do not require the creation of another function or class, ...)

Comment: How do you define "empty"?

Comment: std::array<Something, 0>

Comment: It may help guide answers if you can describe *why* you want "special without specialization"

Comment: Because it is obvious to do it with specialization, and I consider this as a "theoretical" question and I would like to know if there exist a trick (special use with of type_traits for example) that I do not know to do this kind of things.

Comment: `std::array` has a member function [`empty()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/empty), which happens to be declared `constexpr`. Is that what you want?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `std::tuple_size`, as it will also work for `std::array`! See [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/tuple_size). Simply use:

```
std::tuple_size<Type>::value == 0
```

to check if `Type` is an empty `std::tuple<>` or an empty `std::array<T,0>`.

---

With the above, the question remains what happens if `Type` is neither a `std::tuple` not a `std::array`. The general approach I see is this:

```
constexpr bool IsNotTupleOrArray =
  !std::is_class<Type>::value ||
  std::is_same<Type,ExcludeThisClass>::value ||
  sizeof(Type)>1 || // non-portable, works for GCC 4.8+
  ...;

std::conditional< IsNotTupleOrArray,
                  std::false_type,
                  std::tuple_size<Type> >::type::value;
```

which basically means that you have to explicitly exclude other types. For example `is_class<Type>` excludes all fundamental types like `int`, pointers, etc.

Comment: Fine but what will be the result if Type is neither a tuple or an array ?

Comment: @Vincent: Without additional functions or classes, I wouldn't know how to describe your situation *without* using the word "doomed"...

Comment: @Vincent: Although... what exactly *could* `Type` be? Anything? Or only a limited set of other types? Please clarify the rules of this game :)

Comment: @Vincent: I went ahead and edited the answer. Note you can add a condition like `sizeof(Type)>sizeof(int)` as a non-portable test to exclude further types.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to do it without specialization, why not doing it with **overload**? ;) Specializing a function template is sometimes (no, often) a bad idea. With some SFINAE trick it wouldn't be difficult to create an overload that is selected only when those two conditions apply.

However, I already hear you shouting that it's not what you wanted to do: what you wanted is some kind of `if` inside of `f()` that would be executed in case the condition is true, and a corresponding `else` branch that would be executed when the condition is false.

However, notice that this would not be a [*static* if](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/GoingNative-2012/Static-If-I-Had-a-Hammer), but a regular run-time if: in other words, the compiler would know at compile-time with 100% certainty that one of those two branches is never going to be executed (and it would probably issue an annoying warning about it), but it will have to **parse** both branches and prove them legal.

In practice, this means that you won't be able to put statements that depend on the particular type `T` (or on properties of `T`) in order to be compilable. For instance, in the code below `compile_time_expression` determines whether type `T` has a member function `foo()` or a member function `bar()`:

```
T obj;
if (compile_time_expression)
{
    obj.foo();
}
else
{
    obj.bar();
}
```

However, the above won't compile if that particular `T` doesn't have *both* a member function `foo()` and a member function `bar()`: since what you have here is a run-time `if`, the compiler will have to parse both branches and make sure they're both compilable - and then possibly optimize away the one that is never going to be executed.

Unfortunately, C++ does not have any construct such as static if (yet?), so **overloading + SFINAE is the right way to tackle this problem**.